# Chained async methods don't show result in Widget with FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

I am having a problem displaying asynchronous data in a text widget.

I'm doing two chained asynchronous methods to search for the coordinates and then search for the city from the smartphone:

```
Future<String> _getCity() async {
  Future<Position> pos = Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
  String city = "";

  pos.then((result) {
    return result;
  })
  .then((result) async {
    List<Placemark> listPlacemark = await Geolocator().placemarkFromPosition(result);
    return listPlacemark;
  })
  .then((result) {
    return result.first;
  })
  .then((result) {
    city = result.subAdministrativeArea;
    // print( city ); -> Here it's showing correct data in console
  });

  return city;
}
```

The city appears on the console in that print command that is commented out.

To fill the text widget I'm doing this:

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
  child: FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: _getCity(), // a Future<String> or null
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.none:
          return Text('Error loading location');
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return Text('Waiting...');
        default:
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error loading location');
          } else {
            return Text(snapshot.data);
          }
      }
    },
  ),
),
```

I called the _getCity method inside the initState method and it also worked.
The waiting message has already appeared but now everything is blank, what is missing?

I thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

Even if you return a value from the callback of `then()`, the value is not returned from `_getCity()`. You need to return `Future`.

```dart
Future<String> _getCity() async {
  Future<Position> pos = Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);

  return pos.then((result) {
    return result;
  }).then((result) async {
    List<Placemark> listPlacemark = await Geolocator().placemarkFromPosition(result);
    return listPlacemark;
  }).then((result) {
    return result.first;
  }).then((result) {
    return result.subAdministrativeArea;
  });
}
```

---

By the way, do you need so many `then`s?

I've never used `Geolocator()`, so this is just a guess, but some of them may be removed because it looks like `listPlacemark`, `result.first` and `result.subAdministrativeArea` are not `Future` and you just want to extract a value from `List<Position>`. If my guess is right, the following will do.

```dart
Future<String> _getCity() async {
  Future<Position> pos = Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);

  return pos.then((result) async {
    List<Placemark> listPlacemark = await Geolocator().placemarkFromPosition(result);
    return listPlacemark.first.subAdministrativeArea;
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey man! First thank you @kaboc for editing code!
To search for the city from the user's address in real time, you need to get the coordinates of the smartphone and then search for the address. So in practice you only need two 'thens'. I tested your suggestion and the data is returned from the API but it does not display on the device's text widget.

Comment: I'm afraid, it doesn't seem I can be of any more help... I tried on my actual phone, but `getCurrentPosition` won't return anything, showing no error. It is not due to something related to permission. Leaving aside my problem, if the location data was successfully returned by `_getCity()` on your phone, it probably means the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @Donadon I realised that you could reduce `then` more. I updated my answer.